# how to resolve jquery class conflicts when i am using marquee and thick box plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to `marquee` continuously scrolling images and added external links, where it has to popup using `thickbox` mechanism. I am facing `jquery` class conflict issue. Please provide solution for this.

In `thickbox` JavaScript ,starts with

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');//pass where to apply thickbox
    imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
    imgLoader.src = tb_pathToImage;
});
```

and in marquee JavaScript, starts with

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.marquee = function (class) {
        var newMarquee = [],
        ....
    }
});
```

What do I have to do to resolve the conflict issue with `thickbox`?

Comment: What exactly *is* the conflict? Are you getting errors in the console? Is one of them working and not the other?

Comment: used fancy box instead thick box and got working.

Answer (score 0):

The code for marquee seems to be missing an argument in the outer invocation. The function receives $ as an argument, but nothing is being passed in to the function to be aliased to $, change it to:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.marquee = function (class) {
        var newMarquee = [],
        ....
    }
})(jQuery); //pass jQuery into the function
```